# Searching ID or property for match in Mongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

**Goal**:

I want to allow the user to search for a document by ID, or allow other text-based queries.

**Code**:

```
l_search_results = list(
    cll_sips.find(
        {
            '$or': [
                {'_id': ObjectId(s_term)},
                {'s_text': re.compile(s_term, re.IGNORECASE)},
                {'choices': re.compile(s_term, re.IGNORECASE)}
            ]
        }
    ).limit(20)
)
```

**Error**:

`<Whatever you searched for> is not a valid ObjectId`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`s_term` needs to be a valid object ID (or at least in the right format) when you pass it to the `ObjectId` constructor. Since it's sometimes not an ID, that explains why you get the exception.

Try something like this instead:

```
from pymongo.errors import InvalidId

or_filter = [
    {'s_text': re.compile(s_term, re.IGNORECASE)},
    {'choices': re.compile(s_term, re.IGNORECASE)}
]

try:
    id = ObjectId(s_term)
    or_filter.append({ '_id': id })
except InvalidId:
    pass

l_search_results = list(
    cll_sips.find({ '$or': or_filter }).limit(20)
)
```